# How to monitor a directory for file changes without using inotifywait?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, virtual-machine, inotify

I require a VM for developing and my host is where my IDE is. I have discovered that inotifywait does not work with shared folders, as I am sharing a local folder with my Linux guest using Virtual Box.

Basically, I have a simple bash script which needs to watch a directory and wait for any file changes. Inotifywait would be the best option but I cannot get it to work with my shared folder.

I was wondering if there is another option for my problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question over in stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305394/script-to-monitor-for-new-files-in-a-shared-folder-windows-host-linux-guest

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't really have any decent solutions and it was 1 year ago, things could have changed...

Comment: @Erdss4 *Yeah but it doesn't really have any decent solutions* Because there **are** no decent solutions to trying to misuse a state-based data storage structure as an event-based messaging service.  The only reason inotify works is it's hooked into that state-based structure inside the OS kernel.  That can't work on a filesystem shared from another server.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It could work if the inotify calls could be used remotely on the shared resource, but it would require an improvement of the network filesystem protocols.

Comment: @peterh True, but NFSv4 and SMB/CIFS are more than complex enough already...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the sizes of the files and the nature of the changes you could:

- Create a checksum (md5, CRC, SHA256) of the files and watch for changes
- check the size of the files and watch for changes

Comment: Yeah this is what I went for in the end. I just computed the hash of the directory using tar. Every-time there was a change the hash would indicate the file change...

Answer (score 0):

Look at entr (https://eradman.com/entrproject/)

You can do something like this:

while true; do
ls files*.html | entr -pd process.sh;
done